# Python3: how can we close netlink socket blocking recv?

Tags: python, sockets, netlink

I have the raw socket in Python as below to receive netlink messages from linux kernel.

```
socket.socket(socket.AF_NETLINK, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.NETLINK_ROUTE)
```

I am doing blocking `recv` on this socket and want to close it from another Python thread.  However, calling `shutdown(socket.SHUT_RD)` on this socket returns an error (`[Errno95] Operation not supported`)

Why is that? How can we close this socket? I am using Python 3.7

There is no mention of this behavior in
https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket

It states below:

> Note close() releases the resource associated with a connection but does not necessarily close the connection immediately. If you want to close the connection in a timely fashion, call shutdown() before close().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you want to close the connection in a timely fashion, call shutdown() before close()

This statement is about **connected** sockets. TCP sockets are connected, but UDP, Raw, Netlink sockets etc are not. That's why `shutdown` is not supported on such sockets. Use a simple `close` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations! What I actually want to do is to unblock `recv()` so that I can close the thread in which `recv()` is running.  Calling `close()` does not seem unblock `recv()`.  Is that expected?

Comment: @leopoodle: based on "things found on the internet" like [this one](https://github.com/mdlayher/netlink/issues/92) it looks like a `close` in one thread might not wake up the `recv` in the other. Better use non-blocking sockets in combination with `select` or `poll`.